# Infinite sum of indicator functions

Tags: calculus, summation

I have to compute the sum

$$
S(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} S(x,n) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{1}_{n<x<n+1}
$$

where $n = 0,1,2,3,\dots$ and

$$
\mathbb{1}_{n<x<n+1} = \begin{cases}1 \quad \mbox{if } n<x<n+1 \\ 0 \quad \mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

Can you show which is the result of this sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, only the term $S(x,~n)$ when $x-1 \lt n \lt x$ contributes to the sum. If $x$ is not an integer and $x > 0$, only one integer $n$ satisfies this. Therefore $S(x) = 1$. If $x$ is an integer, no $n$ satisfies this, so $S(x) = 0$. Otherwise, if $x < 0$, no $n$ satisfies this as well.

Therefore,
$S(x) = 1$ when $x$ is positive and not an integer and $S(x) = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: I think the conclusion is slightly wrong, $S(x)=0$ when $x$ is an integer or is negative and $S(x)=1$ otherwise.

Comment: @P.Quinton yes, you are right, I had a typo just now. Corrected it now.